# "No -m.cmap file found for ueur"

Tags: fonts

Loading the `upgreek` package causes the following warning:

```
!!! No -m.cmap file found for ueur !!! .
```

I also get this error if I use `\boldsymbol{\uppsi}` (or similar) somemwhere.

```
!!! No -m.cmap file found for ueurb !!! .
```

Are there cmap files for the upgreek characters? I presumem that's what I need.

(Naturally, I have `cmap` loaded -- via `mmap`.)

Comment: as the warning says, there are no cmap files. You will have to write them yourself, or ask the mmap maintainer if they can provide them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I see. Is there any good guide to writing such cmap files myself?